# Tunning gain table to match two-curves

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, curve, pid-controller

I have two data set, let us name them "actual speed" and "desired speed". My main objective is to match actual speed with the desired speed.

But for doing that in my case, I need to tune FF(1x10), Integral(10x8) and Proportional gain table(10x8).

My approach till now was as follows:-

1. First, start the iteration with having 0.1 as the initial value in the first cells(FF[0]) of the FF table
2. Then find the R-square or Co-relation between two dataset( i.e. Actual Speed and Desired Speed)
3. Increment the value of first cell(FF[0]) by 0.25 and then again compute R-square or Co-relation of two data set.
4. Once the cell(FF[0]) value reaches 2(Gains Maximum value. **Already defined by the lab**). Evaluate R-square and re-write the gain value in FF[0] which gives min. error between the two curve.
5. Then tune the Integral and Proportional table in the same way for the same RPM Range
6. Once It is tune then go for higher RPM range and repeat step 2-5 (RPM Range: 800-1000; 1000-1200;....;3000-3200)

Now the problem is that this process is taking way too long time to complete. For example it takes around 1 Hr. time to tune one cell of FF. Which is actually very slow.

If possible, Please suggest any other approach which I can try to tune the tables. I am using MATLAB R2010a and I can't shift to any other version of MATLAB because my controller can communicate with this version only and I can't use any app for tuning since my GUI is already communicating with the controller and those two datasets are being made in real-time

In the given figure, lets us take (X1,Y1) curve as Desired speed and (X2,Y2) curve as Actual speed
[image: **In the given figure, lets us take (X1,Y1) curve as Desired speed and (X2,Y2) curve as Actual speed**.]

**UPDATE**
[image: I AM ALSO ATTACHING THE PROFILE SUMMARY OF IT. PLEASE CHECK.]

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code? try to find the slow parts and speed those up

Comment: but how much can I improve by that?

I mean right now it is taking around 15 min to optimize one cell and in my case there are around 170 cells so 170*15= 2550 minutes to complete the full optimization process. Which is very slow. 

Is there any other way I can approach this problem?

Comment: How to  improve it? wirtting faster code. But we can not see the code, so we can not tell you how to improve

Comment: @AnderBiguri is there any other approach we I can use to find the optimized value?

or finding the Rsquare for each gain value is the only way.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have attached the profile summary with the question. Can you help me now?

Comment: What is in puhsbutton->callback ?

Comment: Pushbutton 1 is the tag of the button pressed by the user in my GUI start the tuning process(Curve matching process) @AnderBiguri

Comment: Do you understand the output of the profiler? almost all the time is in there, so you shoudl go in there and see what takes most of the part of that specific section. You are showing little cooperation

Comment: @AnderBiguri. The purpose of this GUI is to match the actual and desired speed curve. 

This GUI has only one button and that is pushbutton1. So, Once the user press that button, curve matching process will start and this is the reason why majority of the time taken by the program is shared by that button itself. 
If possible please let me know if there is any fast method to do xlsread/xlsopen because I am calling these two lines multiple times. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please, read the documentation for profiling. You can see **inside** what takes time, because maybe inside the pushbutton there is a single line that takes all the time. We want to profile the curvefitting function not the pushbutton. What made you think that we wanted the pushbutton?

Comment: @Ander Biguri 
Sir, Curve fitting function will be called only when the user press the push button. As I said in the previous comment, 

It is the xlsread function which is taking the majority of the time.

Comment: `13232>1854`. Good luck

Comment: @AnderBiguri **Inside** the pushbutton1 call back xlsread has been called multiple of times. 1300 times to be exact. *Taking 70% of the time share*.

I think you are missing something. The xlsread out side is the pre-defined function made by matlab. where Matlab use actx server to communicate between MS Excel and script to read and write.